# Add external JavaScript to Magento backend

Tags: xml, magento

**The goal:**

Googles jQuery file externally linked on every backend site.

**My attempt:**

Adding

```xml
<reference name="head">
  <block type="core/text" name="google.cdn.jquery">
    <action method="setText">
      <text><![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>]]></text>
    </action>
  </block>
</reference>
```

to the local.xml and/or the main.xml (inside design/adminhtml/)

I thought this could work because for the frontend (then inside design/frontend/) it did its job.

**Problem with my attempt:**

Nothing happens. Not even an error or something but exactly nothing. It makes no difference if I add it or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento [doest't like](http://spoon5.com/blog/article/how-to-use-jquery-in-magento) external files. But the good news are you have two options:

The static: Add your jquery include to head.phtml

The dynamic: Follow the way described [here](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-add-external-javascript-css-file-to-magento/)

Comment: *Just now* at this second I've found the answer myself and it's exactly like you say: Adding my include to head.phtml is the solution.

Comment: For others who are interested: The head.phtml can be found at *design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page/head.phtml*, adding `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('google.cdn.jquery'); ?>` to it did the trick in my case!